# app css changes are ignored when building project

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I'm currently learning Blazor Webassembly. I had issues with my styling and I could not figure it out, why my CSS is wrong all the time. Then randomly after some time passed I saw, that my changes on Client/wwwroot/css/app.css are not picked up. In the browser it is still the same as when I created the project.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Problem can be solved by refreshing the browser with **CTRL+F5**